# Routing/forwarding packets between two interfaces

Tags: debian, routing, vmware-workstation

I need to route my PC network traffic through a VMWare machine. What setup I thought about that is using a vm with two interfaces and forcing the PC to send the traffic to `VMNet1` instead of `Ethernet` (using interface metric or routing). The setup is look like the following picture:

[image]

I have enabled `ip_forward` in `/proc/sys/net/ipv4/`, but seems isn't enough.

In the PC I can access to `ens33` and `ens37`:

- Pinging 192.168.1.3 from PC is OK
- Pinging 192.168.1.4 from PC is OK
- ARP table (arp -a) shows 192.168.1.3-4 in 192.168.1.5's entry
- I can't ping 192.168.1.1 through VMNet1 (ping -S 192.168.1.5 192.168.1.1)

In the vm:

- Pinging 192.168.1.1 **only** through ens37 is OK (ping -I ens37 192.168.1.1)

**Question**
With the above details, I think my problem is routing/forwarding incoming packet from `ens33` to `ens37`in the vm, so how to do this?

Further information:

```
~$ ip route
default via 192.168.1.1 dev ens37 proto static metric 101 
192.168.1.0/24 dev ens33 proto kernel scope link src 192.168.1.3 metric 100 
192.168.1.0/24 dev ens37 proto kernel scope link src 192.168.1.4 metric 101 

~$ networkctl status -a
● 1: lo
       Link File: /usr/lib/systemd/network/99-default.link
    Network File: n/a
            Type: loopback
           State: carrier (unmanaged)
         Address: 127.0.0.1
                  ::1

● 2: ens33
       Link File: /usr/lib/systemd/network/99-default.link
    Network File: n/a
            Type: ether
           State: routable (unmanaged)
            Path: pci-0000:02:01.0
          Driver: e1000
          Vendor: Intel Corporation
           Model: 82545EM Gigabit Ethernet Controller (Copper) (PRO/1000 MT Single Port Adapter)
      HW Address: 00:0c:29:2e:5e:a0 (VMware, Inc.)
         Address: 192.168.1.3
                  fe80::a71c:e329:2378:4972

● 3: ens37
       Link File: /usr/lib/systemd/network/99-default.link
    Network File: n/a
            Type: ether
           State: routable (unmanaged)
            Path: pci-0000:02:05.0
          Driver: e1000
          Vendor: Intel Corporation
           Model: 82545EM Gigabit Ethernet Controller (Copper) (PRO/1000 MT Single Port Adapter)
      HW Address: 00:0c:29:2e:5e:aa (VMware, Inc.)
         Address: 192.168.1.4
                  fe80::20c:29ff:fe2e:5eaa
         Gateway: 192.168.1.1 (TP-LINK TECHNOLOGIES CO.,LTD.)
                  fe80::1 (TP-LINK TECHNOLOGIES CO.,LTD.)

~$ ip neigh
192.168.1.103 dev ens37 lladdr 3c:bb:fd:3d:25:00 REACHABLE
192.168.1.103 dev ens33  FAILED
192.168.1.1 dev ens37 lladdr 90:f6:52:03:3b:00 STALE
192.168.1.100 dev ens37 lladdr 40:61:86:e2:dd:00 STALE
192.168.1.1 dev ens33  FAILED
192.168.1.5 dev ens33 lladdr 00:50:56:c0:00:00 STALE


C:\WINDOWS\system32>arp -a

Interface: 192.168.1.100 --- 0x10
  Internet Address      Physical Address      Type
  192.168.1.1           90-f6-52-03-3b-00     dynamic
  ...

Interface: 192.168.1.5 --- 0x1e
  Internet Address      Physical Address      Type
  192.168.1.3           00-0c-29-2e-5e-a0     dynamic
  192.168.1.4           00-0c-29-2e-5e-a0     dynamic
  ...
```

**Edit:** 
I've realized my setup is not very correct despite networking, I mean it's wrong to use multiple interface with same subnet in one system, so I've changed the setup:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This could be because of reverse path filtering. You could try disabling it. The packets are being received and sent on different interfaces and with the default behavior of rp_filter, the packet would be dropped. 
Source: https://access.redhat.com/solutions/53031

Comment: Thanks for you comment, I have checked the `rp_filter` and it seems it's already disabled in my vm machine.